# Declare a static instance of PApplet?

Tags: java, processing

I want to be able to reference PApplet from within a serializable class without having to extend or pass PApplet into the constructor. Is it possible to do this? Here is my failed attempt:

```
import java.io.*;

static PApplet p = new PApplet();

Foo f = new Foo();

void setup()
{
  f.render();
}

static class Foo implements Serializable 
{
  void render()
  {
    p.rect(10,10,10,10);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a little unclear what you're asking: does your PApplet instance have to be static? Does your Foo class have to be static? Or have you just made them static because you think you have to?

Why do you need a separate instance of PApplet? If this is from a Processing sketch, you're already "in" an instance of PApplet, which you can refer to using the **this keyword**.

Here's your code, slightly modified to use the this keyword:

```
import java.io.*;

PApplet p = this;

Foo f = new Foo();

void setup()
{
  f.render();
}

class Foo implements Serializable 
{
  void render()
  {
    p.rect(10,10,10,10);
  }
}
```

However, the this keyword (and the p variable) aren't really necessary. This code does the same thing:

```
import java.io.*;

Foo f = new Foo();

void setup()
{
  f.render();
}

class Foo implements Serializable 
{
  void render()
  {
    rect(10,10,10,10);
  }
}
```

Like I said though, it's a little unclear what you're asking, so maybe you need the p variable for something. The answer is to just use the this keyword and to get rid of the static keywords.